# Intercept open syscall for all binaries

Tags: linux, gcc, ld-preload

I saw that intercepting `fopen` with `LD_PRELOAD` isn't 100% effective (demo below). Is there a catchall way to intercept the open syscall?
My end goal is to present a different file than the one requested (e.g. when `/etc/hosts` is requested, return a stream to `/tmp/my-hosts`).
Would prefer not having to use root, but if I have to, so be it.

EDIT: I want a solution that works on existing binaries. I don't have access to their source.

### bin.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("file", "r");
  if (file) {
      while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
          putchar(c);
      fclose(file);
  } 
}
```

### override.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode) {
    printf("INTERCEPTED\n");
    FILE *(*original_fopen)(const char*, const char*);
    original_fopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    return (*original_fopen)(path, mode);
}

FILE *fopen64(const char *path, const char *mode) {
    printf("INTERCEPTED64\n");
    FILE *(*original_fopen64)(const char*, const char*);
    original_fopen64 = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    return (*original_fopen64)(path, mode);
}
```

### Makefile

```
clean:
    rm -f bin-stat bin-dyn override.so

bin-stat: bin.c
    gcc -static -Wall -Werror -o bin-stat bin.c

bin-dyn: bin.c
    gcc -Wall -Werror -o bin-dyn bin.c

override.so: override.c
    gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o override.so override.c -ldl

test: clean bin-stat bin-dyn override.so
    LD_PRELOAD=./override.so ./bin-dyn
    LD_PRELOAD=./override.so ./bin-stat
```

As you can see, `bin-stat` is compiled without dynamic linking to libc, and as you can guess, `LD_PRELOAD` won't work:

```
nitz@mars:~/Desktop/test-ld (master %)$ make test
rm -f bin-stat bin-dyn override.so
gcc -static -Wall -Werror -o bin-stat bin.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -o bin-dyn bin.c
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o override.so override.c -ldl
LD_PRELOAD=./override.so ./bin-dyn
INTERCEPTED
is file
LD_PRELOAD=./override.so ./bin-stat
is file
nitz@mars:~/Desktop/test-ld (master %)$
```

Comment: dynamic functions cannot depend / override static functions. You would have to create a `override.a` file containing this code and link against that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre will that require me to recompile `bin`? I've added an edit clarifying I can't recompile it. I need an outside solution

Comment: In that case, your makefile isn't representative. You should put the `bin.o` in input of your link commands. I would try `gcc -c override.c; gcc -static -Wall -Werror -o bin-stat bin.o override.o`

Comment: now I have a doubt: about the files you can't recompile, you don't have the .o files but just the executable files right? in that case, neither of the solutions will work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre figured as much. I think I'm staring at something like replacing the syscalls at runtime

Comment: That or disassemble and reassemble, redirecting the syscalls to an added segment If there are a lot of exes this can be tedious. Aren't there some low-level Linux services that trace os calls? maybe there's something to copy from.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout kprobes or system tap to intercept system calls.